# Generate photons from radio waves

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, sensor

Photons can generate electricity via the photoelectric effect, but is it possible to go the other direction? Generate scintillations from radio waves?

The obvious answer would be to attach a light-emitting diode to a radio antenna and see what happens, or can you? I assume an LED has some minimum voltage, so that the tiny voltages generated by radio waves would be insufficient. I think a radio wave is typically a few millivolts, so it would have to be an LED or other scintillator that would operate at that sensitivity.

Comment: A friend is a big DX'er (long distance contacts). On 160 meters he used a 160m antenna wire, supported by a helium weather balloon. He put a neon bulb at the top, which flashed nicely on transmit (serving as a warning to small planes). Probably not what you are thinking about...

Comment: Waves and photons are complementary descriptions of electromagnetic radiation. Radio waves *are* photons in a particular energy band (and vice versa). Both descriptions always apply (though one is often easier to use than the other).

Answer (score 1):

For ionizing radiation, a scintillation detector is used. You need much lower frequencies to be upconverted instead.

There is R&D being done for it, mainly to try to do direct conversion of RF signals to optical fiber signals. See for instance 
http://www.interferencetechnology.com/converting-radio-waves-into-light/
But actually it doesn't create the photons, it very slightly affects a small member and coated with silver nitride which is monitored by a laser light which thus gets modulated.

Others are working on Terahertz technology, in between IR and GHz radio wave technology. See eg https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131249/can-i-turn-radio-waves-into-lightw

Meta materials are being researched to convert directly microwaves to power, you can always drive optical diodes with that. You can google that.

One way or another you need to have multiple interactions to go from photons at a low energy to ones at a high energy, such as the meta material example above.

Comment: The Danish technology is interesting. That is the kind of phenomenon I am interested in. I did not realize it was so hard to do.

Comment: Yeap, not easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are no photons in near zone around the antenna. In this zone the wavefront is a continuous physical surface. In far zone the wavefront breaks, giving many discrete surfaces. Any one is the wavefront of a single photon, and the size is in order of the wavelenght. In the case of radio weves, the photon have a size in order to meters, e.g. 10, 20, 40, 80, 160 meters. These sizes difficult detection of quantum nature of radiation. But this nature always exists.